# Not able to run COPY INTO commands during spark write in Snowflake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
GET @spark_connector_load_stage_jtVp1DVrvm/ file:///tmp/dummy_location_spark_connector_tmp/

PUT file:///tmp/dummy_location_spark_connector_tmp/ @spark_connector_load_stage_jtVp1DVrvm

copy into <table_name> FROM @spark_connector_load_stage_jtVp1DVrvm/7sizvhBNgR/ 
FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE=CSV
    FIELD_DELIMITER='|'
    NULL_IF=()
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='TZHTZM YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9'
    DATE_FORMAT='TZHTZM YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9'
    BINARY_FORMAT=BASE64
  )
```

It successfully runs GET and PUT, when running COPY INTO, it exactly fails after 5 mins.

Tried using different warehouses, and checked the Parameters for timeout, its 7200s (2hrs).

Issue in spark paremeter ? Or snowflake parameter ?

Comment: Is there any error message (in query_history or elsewhere)? Does it load any records during the time that it’s running?

Comment: Getting this error: SQL execution got cancelled.

Comment: If it always fails after 5 min, then it must be some parameter either in Spark or Snowflake. To understand this better you should open a case with Snowflake Support and provide the query id of the failing `COPY INTO`. Snowflake Support team should be able to confirm if it's a parameter from Snowflake side.